# Why are my objects location randomised but not showing up?

Tags: ios, swift, random, shuffle, ios10

I am trying to randomise a set of meals (currently 5) such an array of meal objects that I've created which have a property mealTitles. I press randomise, using code:

```
func shuffleArray<T>(array: Array<T>) -> Array<T>
{
    var array = array
    for index in ((0 + 1)...array.count - 1).reversed()
    {
        // Random int from 0 to index-1
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index-1)))

        // Swap two array elements
        // Notice '&' required as swap uses 'inout' parameters
        swap(&array[index], &array[j])
    }

    return array
}
```

I use a shuffle button and look at if it is shuffling Such:

```
@IBAction func shuffleButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    shuffleArray(array: myMeals)
    print("Objects: \(shuffleArray(array: myMeals))")
    print(myMeals[0].mealTitle, myMeals[1].mealTitle, myMeals[2].mealTitle)
}
```

This code produces in the console this:

```
Objects: [<ParseStarterProject_Swift.Meal: 0x6080002747c0>, <ParseStarterProject_Swift.Meal: 0x60800026ea40>, <ParseStarterProject_Swift.Meal: 0x60000027b400>, <ParseStarterProject_Swift.Meal: 0x60000026d980>, <ParseStarterProject_Swift.Meal: 0x608000267d80>]
Sausages and Mash Chicken Korma Fajitas
Objects: [<ParseStarterProject_Swift.Meal: 0x60000027b400>, <ParseStarterProject_Swift.Meal: 0x60800026ea40>, <ParseStarterProject_Swift.Meal: 0x60000026d980>, <ParseStarterProject_Swift.Meal: 0x6080002747c0>, <ParseStarterProject_Swift.Meal: 0x608000267d80>]
Sausages and Mash Chicken Korma Fajitas
```

I.e it looks like the location is changing but the meal Title stay the same.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shuffle method returns a new array that is a shuffled version of the old array, but you aren't doing anything with that return value in your code.  You need to assign the shuffled array to your property.

```
myMeals = shuffleArray(array: myMeals)
```